# I am receiving an error "no matching function to call" in the line ifstream input_file(filename);

Tags: c++

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    cout << "Give the name of the input file : ";
    string filename;
    cin >> filename;

    cout << "Reading from " << filename << "..." << endl;

    ifstream input_file(filename);
    if( !input_file ) {
        // stuff...
    }
}
```

Comment: You are probably compiling with an older C++ dialect. `std::ifstream` constructor that takes a `const string&` is a C++11 thing. Make sure you pass something like `-std=c++11` or whatever option your compiler takes.

Comment: Now `std::ifstream::open` is overloaded to take an `std::string`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have `#include <fstream>` and `using namespace std;` in your code, then change this:

`ifstream input_file(filename);`

To this:

`ifstream input_file(filename.c_str());`

In your compiler's version of C++, the `std::ifstream` constructor takes only a `const char*` as input, not a `std::string`.  C++11 is needed to pass in a `std::string` as-is.  If your compiler supports C++11, maybe you have not enabled it. Check your compiler's documentation.